# Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical-data

Here's my data

my dataframe name is `tab`

```
        user_id     len
        barcode
0        1          490
1        2          71
2        3          1
3        5          1
```

This is my code

```
tab = tab[tab[('len', 'barcode')]]
```

tab.columns

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['len', 'user_id'], ['barcode', '']],
           labels=[[1, 0], [1, 0]])
```

This code on my routine notebook and works more than 10 times, but it not works anymore

Comment: What is `df.columns` ?

Comment: Edited in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is problem your second level name is empty string.

So need:

```
a = tab[('len', '')]
print (a)
0    490
1     71
2      1
3      1
Name: (len, ), dtype: int64
```

If you want replace all empty strings in columns names:

```
tab = tab.rename(columns={'':'b'})
a = tab[('len', 'b')]
print (a)
0    490
1     71
2      1
3      1
Name: (len, b), dtype: int64
```

But better is remove `[]` for remove MultiIndex in columns:

```
tab = pd.pivot_table(barcode,index="user_id",values="barcode",‌​aggfunc='size')
tab = tab.reset_index()
```

Comment: It comes from pivoting

`tab = pd.pivot_table(barcode,index=["user_id"],values=["barcode"],aggfunc=[len])`
`tab = tab.reset_index()`

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Check last edit of my answer.

Comment: Ok, nice explanation, it is helpful